# How would I rotate different users in a PHP script

Tags: php, sorting

Ok so i have this problem i am trying figure out. I have 5 users that i need to send an email to one after another. So if i just sent an email to John then the next time the script is called i need to send an email to Joe

```
John
Joe
Ashley
Brandon
Bill
```

The problem i am trying to address is that how do I know who is next in line to be sent to. I requirements ask for me to take the form fields and create a .txt. file in a Leads directory.That part is not to hard, but how do I know that which user is next. I was thinking of a counter of some sort but i really dont know what the best way to do this...

Comment: once you are saying that the script will send mail to one user at one time. then you say that the form is responsible for sending to all. be clear with what your program will do. one or many?

Comment: I need to send an email (one email at a time) to the next user ...not all at once

Answer (score 2):

So you have a script that sends an email. There's a HTML form that users fill out to submit to use that script.

There is no relationship from one submit to another, so you have to make the relationship to do the round robin.

In other words, somewhere on the backend, database or flat file (text file), you have to flag who was last emailed.

Does this makes sense?

Comment: It makes sense...i am using a combination of the different answers

Answer (score 1):

Why not just query a database (get the list) and itterate through the userse to email to?

something like:

```
$users = array('john' => 'john@email.com', 'Joe' => 'joe@email.com');

foreach($users as $name => $email){
  email_user($name, $email, $subject, $message); 
    // email_user is just a made up email function.
}
```

Comment: the only problem with this approach is that its sending them all at once when i only send one now and the next time the script is called i need to find the next user from a persistent place

Comment: You could just as easily set flags in a database / text file to keep track of users (I would suggest db, as it simplifies the process).

Answer (score 1):

If you put all the information in a .txt file, you can add something like "|sent" behind the username. That way you can (after using explode()) see which user already received a mail.

Also, if you tell us more about what you're actually trying to do, we can give even better answers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the data about which user is next in some sort of persistent storage like a database or a file.

Using a file:

```
$users = array( "John", "Joe", "Ashley", "Brandon", "Bill" );

$next_user_index = file_get_contents( "next-user" );

$user_to_send_to = $users[ $next_user_index ];

file_put_contents( "next-user", ( $user_to_send_to + 1 ) % count( $users ) );
```

Comment: hey @mat what is this doing ..is next-user a file

Comment: Yes, next-user would be a file in the same directory as the running script. Its not a very good place to put the file though, it was just for example purposes! The contents of the file would be a number representing where in the list of users you will look for the next user.

Comment: mat one last thing ( $user_to_send_to + 1 ) the output is always 1

Comment: Sorry, you're right. It should be $next_user_index + 1 instead.